# How to insert .txt into Excel?

Tags: c#, excel

My .txt file has values separated by space. I want to store this in an Excel sheet with each value separated by space. I want complete first column of Excel sheet to be filled with '1' and after that my data of .txt should be stored in separate cols each.

Can someone help me complete the code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelExample
{
class CreateExcelDoc
{
    private Excel.Application app = null;
    private Excel.Workbook wb = null;
    private Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;
    private Excel.Range workSheet_range = null;
    public CreateExcelDoc()
    {
        createDoc();
    }
    public void createDoc()
    {
        try
        {
            app = new Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = true;
            wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
            sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets[1];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write("Error");
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        wb.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\AniKet\Desktop\testdata.xls");

    }

    public void CloseExcel()
    {
        wb.Saved = true;

            app.Quit();
    }


    private void btnXlsConvert_Click()
    {
        StreamReader s = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\AniKet\Desktop\Project Work\SpatioTemporalFeature\ABHASHDEKAACTIONDistorted Mode");
        string line = "";
        while ((line = s.ReadLine()) != null) {
            string[] arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

            int value = arr.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
            {
               arr
            }

        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        CreateExcelDoc excell_app = new CreateExcelDoc();

        excell_app.CloseExcel();
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
private void btnXlsConvert_Click()
{
    StreamReader s = new StreamReader(
        @"C:\Users\AniKet\Desktop\Project Work\SpatioTemporalFeature\blah blah");
    string line = "";

    int row = 1;

    while ((line = s.ReadLine()) != null) {

        sheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = 1;
        int col = 2;

        string[] arr = line.Split(' ');  // this was changed

        int value = arr.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
        {
            sheet.Cells[row, col++].Value = arr[i];
        }

        row++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. but the code is not working properly. There is some problem with storing of data in string array. I tried to display data from string array using `Console.WriteLine(arr[1]);` for which I am getting array out of bound exception while for `Console.WriteLine(arr[0]);` the output is blank which means array is not able to store data from .txt for some reason.

Comment: My bad...  I took your original code carte-blanche and didn't pay much attention.  I think the line string[] might have been in error, as it was invoking a second `ReadLine()`.  Look at the modification (annotated in the code above) and see if that helps.

Comment: sorry that is my mistake. It should be `string[] arr = s.ReadLine().Split(' ');` as I want to read from .txt and not console. But, even after doing this I get System.NullReferenceException. Plz help me resolve.

Comment: I had exactly that in my original response, but I think that's the problem.  `s.ReadLine()` is reading a SECOND line from your file.  The first was read on the `while` loop.  The way you have your original example coded, you are skipping every other line.  If your file has an odd number of lines, you will get a null reference because `s.ReadLine().Split` yields nothing.  Can you try changing the code to `line.Split()`, as above and see if it helps?

Comment: This code is working but I am facing few issues. The text file I want to store contains data `325.762468575136 279.298876476974 4868.68544600939 1.10961923847695 8089703.16396659 226.605218091523 97.6742962078548 9.71830985915493 16.943661971831 9216.4196216552 62.9441248429543 87.4616147589764` all this data goes in 2nd col instead of going to each col differently. If I use simple data like `4 5 6 2` given with single space the data stores correctly each in different cols. Another issue that I am facing is that exel file is not saving. If I open generated file using excel, it is blank.

Answer (score 0):

With a textfile containing lines like this:

```
325.762468575136 279.298876476974 4868.68544600939 1.10961923847695 8089703.163‌​96659 226.605218091523 97.6742962078548 9.71830985915493 16.943661971831 9216.419‌​6216552 62.9441248429543 87.4616147589764
```

This works for me:
For each line(while-loop):
1. save all values without the whitespaces to a string-array
2. set the value of the first column to "1" and write the values from the textfile to the .xls-file
3. Close the stream
4. delete the file, if it exists already
5. Save the  new .xls - file

```
private void btnXlsConvert_Click()
{

    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(file_path);
    string line;
    int rowIndex = 1;

    while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] values = line.Split(' ');

        sheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1].Value = 1;
        for (int columnIndex = 2; columnIndex < values.Length + 2;columnIndex++)
        {
            sheet.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex].Value = values[columnIndex - 2];
        }
        rowIndex++;
    }

    stream.Close();

    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Timmo\Desktop\testdata.xls"))
            File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Timmo\Desktop\testdata.xls");

        wb.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\AniKet\Desktop\testdata.xls");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```